# Why does the default UI menu bar for "Machine->Save State" is unchecked in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot

You get to the option of changing the VM's menu bar (aka File menu) UI by right clicking on a VM -> Settings... -> User Interface

Is there any special reason for that?
Is there a reason not to save state that way?
Any other recommended way?

Comment: That's really a question for the Virtual Box developers, though if I were you I'd check their documentation to see if they've explained that already. "Why" questions aren't a good fit because they are open to interpretation and cannot usually be answered with a single, correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

To protect the user, by default VirtualBox does not save a snapshot of the machine state when closing a virtual machine, because not all snapshots are worth saving.

Not checking the *Save State* (*Settings* -> *User Interface* -> *Machine* -> *Save State*) option by default provides undo changes to the system (including system files, installed applications, and system/application settings) functionality similar to the System Restore feature in Windows.

VirtualBox is frequently used to test software before installing it on the host OS or on a production machine. After the test is completed the user does not always want to save the changes that were made to the guest OS by the installed software that was tested for these reasons:

1. The software being tested didn't work or was unsuitable for the purpose for which it was downloaded.
2. The software worked as expected, but it did not work as well as other similar software that was also tested.
3. The software worked as expected, but after the testing is completed it is no longer necessary to keep it installed on the guest OS.

Not saving the machine state when closing the virtual machine can also be used to recover from system malfunctions or other problems in the guest OS.